# Are equal-time commutators well-defined in QFT?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-entanglement, commutator

I'm working through some QFT course notes and I just want to check that my understanding of equal-time commutators is correct.

I don't have much to go on -- the notes rather cryptically insert the statement "**Key**: **equal time** commutators $[\hat{p}(t),\hat{q}(t)]$" between the hat-fitting part of canonical quantization $p \rightarrow \hat{p}$; $q \rightarrow \hat{q}$; $[\hat{p},\hat{q}] = -i$ and the quantization of the Hamiltonian -- and Zee doesn't mention the equal-time commutator at the equivalent part of his explanation of canonical quantization.

Staring at the expression $[\hat{p}(t),\hat{q}(t)]$ suggests $\hat{p}$ and $\hat{q}$ probably refer to the same object, meaning I don't have to worry about any Lorentz transformation shenanigans between two different objects. Further, if the $\hat{p}$ and $\hat{q}$ *did* belong to different objects, the commutator would be $0$ from the QM "identity" $[p_i,q_j] \propto \delta_{ij}$.

Is my understanding correct? Also, is there any situation where different objects $i$ and $j$ could have correlated $p_i$ and $q_j$ that might run into Lorentz transformation issues? (In particular, I could imagine entanglement showing up here -- if it does, what does it do to the equal-time commutator $[\hat{p}_i(t),\hat{q}_j(t)]$; or, rather, how does that commutator affect the resulting physics?)

Comment: In QFT, "equal time" doesn't mean "same space-time event", so there are Lorentz transformation schenanigans to worry about.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what your question is.

Comment: @Javier I'm worried about "equal-time" running into relativity of simultaneity issues. I hoped to avoid that by saying $p$ and $q$ must refer to the same space-time event, but Prof. Legolasov suggested that's not true. (That then brings up other questions -- is the commutator defined for only one frame at a time? If it's defined for all frames it seems like a pretty strong statement.) Finally, I had an additional question about how correlations might work in the original, incorrect 'same space-time event' context, but I suppose that point is now moot.

Comment: @Natavi are you concerned about fields? Using the symbols $\hat p$ and $\hat q$ suggests (to me, at least) that you're doing standard, non-relativistic quantum mechanics.  Normally in QFT one writes field commutators as $[\hat \phi(x,t),\hat \pi(y,t)] = i\delta(x-y)$ or something along those lines.